Cross browser cache problems on Android
We have a website that you can also use as a PWA.
One user used it as PWA (coming from chrome) on her Android device.
Since a few weeks, she can't log in her account anymore, both using the PWA or the chrome browser. She also freshly installed Firefox and has the same problem. If she uses other login accounts on the same device for the website, they also don't work. If she uses her desktop PC, she can login (so it is a local problem on her phone).
She also deleted the browser cache on her smartphone, which didn't help.
So

Only occurs on her Android phone
Happens with different browsers (so not a browser cache problem?)
May be related to the site being installed as a PWA before
Can be reproduced with different credentials on her phone

Is there some kind of cross-browser cache or another place, where android may have cached some data?
